# Borg Backup stuck at "Remote: Replaying segments 0%"

Tags: borgbackup

I’m running a offsite backup with borg backup (client & server version: 1.1.10). My biggest repository gets stuck on the status "Remote: Replaying segments   0%". I had the same status for my other repositories, but there it progressed. First, I can observe the borg process doing CPU load on the server, but after several minutes the the process vanishes without anything happening on the client side.

Did this happened to you before? Any ideas how to solve this?

Edit: It might be relevant that I received and Input/output error before on the server for the USB HDD containing the backups, I then restarted the server and it was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a faulty drive to me. I would recommend to check the drive's SMART values by running `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX`.

It the drive is not faulty, it could have been the case that your drive entered a low power mode. Should this happen again, you can try to make power management less aggressive by running `sudo hdparm -B 127 /dev/sdX`, for more information on this please refer to `hdparm`'s [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/hdparm/hdparm.8.en.html).